# Stop TFS from showing a file in Pending Changes for a save action

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When my cs file is open and I make no changes except just clicking the save icon, it thinks some time stamp has changed and lists the file in pending changes.
So annoying! Is there a setting for this?

Comment: Why are you saving the file if you're not making any changes to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TOOLS -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment, there are dropdowns that will let you configure what happens when saving or editing a file.

You can change the Save behaviour to auto-checkout, or prompt for checkout, or to display the Save As dialog.

However it isn't possibly to do anything else when saving. So I believe it is not possible to do what you're asking through VS alone.

You could install the pretty cool CodeMaid extension, which is the only extension I could find that lets you toggle the read-only state of a file.
See http://www.codemaid.net/documentation/#andmore
Once the file is writable, you should be able to save the file without it appearing in Pending Changes.

Answer (score 0):

don't click save, just close the file, this will then not change the time stamp. your local workspace will monitor changes in files BUT will not compare them to source, in fact the file shouldn't need to be checked out unless you make a change.